# How to put IFNULL

Tags: mysql

I have column in table1 where name column has lot of rows as null

```
table1.name=table2.userID
```

So I m trying to put IFNULL condition as this

```
select (IFNULL(name,'empty'))
```

But My output table after exceution comes blank.

Comment: `CASE name is null THEN 'empty' ELSE name END as name`

Comment: OR `IF(name is null, 'empty', name) as name`

Comment: The problem is `table1.name=table2.userID`. This will never be true for those rows where `table1.name` has a null value. You need to show your *complete* SQL and you will then probably end up needing to do an *outer join* instead of an *inner join*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work

```
SELECT IFNULL(`name`, 'empty') FROM `tablename`
```